# SQL Server selection and update query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Question

I am trying to create an UPDATE Query that will be running on SQL Server Agent Daily... however im having trouble getting the right value selected from the table..

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (StaffID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(70))

CREATE TABLE EntryLine (EntryID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
StaffID INT,
EntryDetails VARCHAR(500),
EntryDate DATETIME,
Count INT)

CREATE TABLE Timesheet (TimesheetID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
StaffID INT
StartDate DATETIME,
EndDate DATETIME)
```

Example Data

```
StaffID Name        
   1    John        
   2    Ian     

EntryID StaffID EntryDetails    EntryDate          count 
   1       1       test1    28/06/2015 07:58:06      1
   2       1       test2    28/06/2015 12:03:47      2
   3       1       test3    28/06/2015 13:01:12      3
   4       1       test4    28/06/2015 17:34:56      4
   5       2       test5    28/06/2015 07:48:24      1
   6       2       test6    28/06/2015 17:31:42      2

TimesheetID StaffID      StartDate            EndDate
    1          1    28/06/2015 07:58:06        NULL
    2          2    28/06/2015 07:48:24        NULL
```

As you can see I have set the EndDate as NULL currently in the Timesheet Table. Now what should happen is the query would UPDATE the EndDate to the last entry of the day from the table EntryLine, so the final data would be:

```
TimesheetID StaffID       StartDate                 EndDate
     1         1     28/06/2015 07:58:06       28/06/2015 17:34:56
     2         2     28/06/2015 07:48:24       28/06/2015 17:31:42
```

I have a counter column already (Count) which counts the number of entries per staff per day so I dont know if I should utilize this or base the UPDATE query on the latest date of the day.

please could someone advise me on how I could use this query to UPDATE my table where the:

- EndDate IS NULL
- The StaffID matches
- The EndDate is the SAME DAY as the StartDate

  ```
  select
  EntryLine.StaffID,
  COUNT(count)FieldCounter,
  MAX(EntryLine.EntryDate)EntryDate,
  dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, EntryLine.EntryDate))GenericDate

  from EntryLine
  GROUP BY EntryLine.StaffID, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, EntryLine.EntryDate))
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery for the `UPDATE`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d1d2/2/0)

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.EndDate = (
                    SELECT MAX(EntryDate) 
                    FROM EntryLine 
                    WHERE 
                        StaffID = t.StaffID 
                        AND CAST(EntryDate AS DATE) = CAST(t.StartDate AS DATE)
                    )
FROM Timesheet t
WHERE t.EndDate IS NULL
```

---

Another approach using `JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d1d2/5/0)

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.EndDate = a.MaxEntryDate
FROM Timesheet t
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
        StaffId, 
        CAST(EntryDate AS DATE) AS EntryDate,
        MAX(EntryDate) AS MaxEntryDate
    FROM EntryLine
    GROUP BY StaffId, CAST(EntryDate AS DATE)
)a
    ON a.StaffID = t.StaffID
    AND CAST(t.StartDate AS DATE) = a.EntryDate
WHERE t.EndDate IS NULL
```

Comment: just applied the query above to my scenario and works perfect, I had tried using a correlated subquery but I got the CAST part wrong.. thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery for that .

```
     UPdate T 
        set T.EndDate = X.Exittime
        FROM Timesheet T JOIN (select StaffID,Max(EntryDate) as Exittime from EntryLine Group BY StaffID)X 
        ON X.StaffID = T.StaffID 
         AND CAST(t.StartDate AS DATE) = CAST(X.Exittime AS DATE)
where T.EndDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to make other(third) table for the same data i.e. duplication of DATA,

**just use this query to get the required result:**

(**Third Table** you created is **not necessary** at all)

```
SELECT staffid,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, entrydate, 102) AS ForDate,
       Min(entrydate)                   AS EntryTime,
       Max(entrydate)                   AS ExitTime
FROM   entryline
GROUP  BY staffid,
          CONVERT(VARCHAR, entrydate, 102)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Please Also see my answer and make this correct, +1 (if it is)!

Comment: You can make a View (as you know view is not a table and does not take up space) using the above code and execute the view only whenever you require it.